# How to implement defects categorization in Allure 2 with Python py.test?

Tags: python, reporting, pytest, allure

In [Allure 2 documentation](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_categories) it's stated that defects may be categorized.
Artem Eroshenko in his [Allure 2 presentation](https://habrahabr.ru/company/jugru/blog/337386/) also mentioned that for this purpose `categories.json` config file should be created with regex for categories:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Outdated selectors",
    "messageRegex": ".*Unable to locate element.*",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken"]
  },
  {
    "name": "Browser cluster problems",
    "messageRegex": ".*Timed out .* from renderer.*",
    "matchedStatuses": ["broken"]
  }
]
```

But there are no details in the docs about actual implementation of this feature. Where is this file should be located? Is this feature implemented in `py.test` `allure 2` adaptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place `categories.json` file to `allure-results` folder. For more details see other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46222758/3915166