# Configuration in Allure to Cucumber in Ruby

Tags: ruby, configuration, cucumber, allure

I need to configure the following params:

```
environment, trend, history, executors, retries,
```

etc. I need these params for cucumber to work with ruby. I searched in a lot of places and I did not find much. I would appreciate if you can provide these params.

Comment: I found an answer: Simply generate the report using one of Allure CI plugins (Jenkins/Teamcity/Bamboo) to enrich your report with history and executor info.

To add an environments to your report create an environment.properties file:

some.property.name=some-value 

and place such file to your allure-results folder (the folder that contains allure xml files)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### History

Allure stores history information to `allure-report/history` folder during report generation. So you need to copy such folder from previous launch into your `allure-results` before you generate the report.

*History features are handled out of the box by Allure CI plugins*

### Executor info

To add an information about your test executor create a file `executor.json` in your `allure-results`:

```
{
  "name": "Jenkins",
  "type": "jenkins",
  "url": "http://example.org",
  "buildOrder": 13,
  "buildName": "allure-report_deploy#13", 
  "buildUrl": "http://example.org/build#13",
  "reportUrl": "http://example.org/build#13/AllureReport",
  "reportName": "Demo allure report"
}
```

In the report such information will be displayed like this:

[image: Executor info]

*Allure CI plugins will add executor information for you*

### Categories

You can also add custom problem categories in the report. Create file `categories.json` and place it into your results folder:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Ignored tests",
    "messageRegex": ".*ignored.*",
    "matchedStatuses": [
      "skipped"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Infrastructure problems",
    "messageRegex": ".*RuntimeException.*",
    "matchedStatuses": [
      "broken"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Outdated tests",
    "messageRegex": ".*FileNotFound.*",
    "matchedStatuses": [
      "broken"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Regression",
    "messageRegex": ".*\\sException:.*",
    "matchedStatuses": [
      "broken"
    ]
  }
]
```

[image: Allure Categories]

### Retries

Retries are handled by default. For each test Allure generates `historyId` (usually it is md5(fullName + parameterValues)). If report contains few results with the same `historyId` Allure only displays latest, other are marked as retries and available from `Retries` section on test result page.

For example, if you run your test 3 times (first 2 are broken, latest is passed, Allure will display such test as passed)

[image: Allure retries]
[image: Allure retries]

Comment: Thanks! it's a lot of information! Do you known how change the title and subtitle in the report?, because it show me: Title: Allure Report unknown Subtitle: unknown - unknown (Unknown)