# How to generate allure reports after run testNG test for several times

Tags: testng, allure

I have recently tried to API load testing, and I choose maven+OKHTTP+allure reports+jenkins, 
  when I just try one time run everything is fine, the reports get generated successfully but after that I make the test run for 100 times, 
  then I just look at the reports - it's only showing the first time runs.
  Did anyone face the same issue? Please help.

[TestNGcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGN2d.png)
  [Allureports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWEK.png)

Comment: Please check keep past html reports check box in jenkins. In case your jenkins job has it.

Answer (score 0):

Allure shows only latest result per test case, other are displayed in test retries section. For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46222758/3915166

Comment: Given this behavior, what is the best way for anyone running one test case on several different devices and needs to show this difference in the report?